# Multiple photo upload zone e.g. before photos and after photos

Tags: forms, gui-design, file-input, photos

I am working on an app that lets users fill in a report of the job they have been given. These reports are generally of physical assets. e.g. a fish tank.

In the report, the user has to show proof of the job completion by taking before and after photos. For this, I was thinking of having two photo upload options one for before photos on like Step 1 and after photos on step 4. See image below for reference.

[image]

After the user publishes the report it then displays all the data on the report profile. Where I have different modules displaying all the data. One of the modules is IMAGES where all the images uploaded from before and after are displayed.

[image]

**I need help in:**

1. What is the best way to get the users to **upload or take **before** and **after** images**
2. How to better **display the before and after images.**

Answer (score 1):

and welcome to the site!

I am not really sure what you ask for - do you have any indicators that your current solution does not meet your users' expectations? Especially regarding the report pages - who is using them? I won't expect that the person doing the inspection looks at these pages (has taken the images  herself, so nothing new here). Before we can recommend improvements, we need information on the tasks to solve and the questions to answer based on the pages, for both user groups (for report creation and report viewing).

Regarding your upload page, I would have two remarks not directly related to uploading:

- Replace labels "Step1" by meaningful description (incl. step number) such as "1 - Inspection". In this way, the user can orient herself what to expect.
- Give your users a hint where to upload the after images: Do not write "Only upload before images", write "You can upload after images in a later step".

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Regarding more info on this. At the moment users upload both the before and after images in one upload without any category of before and after. 


Reports are filled in by the tradies in the field during the inspection of the Stormwater asset which is owned by the local council.


Reports are viewed by the admin/manager and someone from the council side.


Hope that helps. 


Also thanks for your two remarks I am aware of them and still working on this. I just did a quick design to be able to show reference for my question.